# How to remove a css style from elementor-lite.min.css file

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, elementor

How to remove a line from elementor plugin frontend-lite.min.css file without editing this file?

This is the style

```
.elementor iframe
{ width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If I want to remove this line:
,`width: 100%;`, is there anyway I can do that without editing the css file?
I try to give width different value, but none of them work in my situation. The only way to fix my problem is to remove this line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it by JavaScript or using jQuery. Catch it by class name ex.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('elementor iframe').style.width = "width you want";
```

Comment: Thank you, can I use it to remove width: 100%; instead of setting  width to other value?

Comment: You can change it to empty string or set on auto.

Answer (score 0):

#### Link your preferred CSS class attributes in a file after the Library

Example:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="library.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` <- Your CSS file with preferred attributes

[Or alter with JS DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp)